# Why chrome-extension doesn't change the images?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am new to chrome-extension and currently studying it. Im reading http://talks.codegram.com/creating-basic-chrome-extensions#/basic_example_4 the css tweaks already works but not with the changing of image...

**mainifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "TrollFaces",
  "version" : "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version" : 2,
  "description": "Must turn Codegram team members pics into troll faces.",
  "permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/*", "background"],
  "browser_action": {"default_icon": "16x16.png","default_popup": "popup.html"},
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      // Change 'matches' attribute to load content
      // script only in pages you want to.
      "js": ["jquery.min.js", "contentscript.js"],
      "matches": ["http://*/*"],
      "css": ["basics.css"]
    }
  ]
}
```

**contentscript.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Trollface image must be at 'my_extension/images/trollface.jpg'.
  var trollface = chrome.extension.getURL("images/trollface.jpeg");
  $('#content article img').each(function(index, image){
    $(image).attr('src', trollface);
  });
});
```

using inspect element over the photo which is not displaying

```
<img alt="Txus" height="150" src="chrome-extension://fdigngaajlfopnpffgcapbdekkbicngb/images/trollface.jpeg" width="225">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the image (or any resource) to be *"usable in the context of a web page"* you have to declare it as a *web accessible resource* in the **[relevant section](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources.html)** of your **manifest.json**. E.g.:

**In manifest.json:**

```
...
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "images/trollface.jpeg"
],
...
```

Comment: thanks! is it a new feauture for manifest? it is not included in the page im reading

Comment: Unfortunately, based on questions/problems posted here by people using _some tutorial to get started_ with Chrome extensions, it seems a great deal of those tutorials are out-dated. Refer to the **[official documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/index.html)** for up-to-date info.